# How can I remove this voiceover icon?

Tags: macos, accessibility

This icon with a microphone and "Wake Up" is annoying and I want to remove it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've enabled "Voice Control" from the Accessibility pane of System Preferences.

(Also called "Speech Commands" or something similar in earlier versions of MacOS.)

Comment: I realise it is the chess application which turns on this voiceover. Only a restart can remove this.